# $\nu_3(n!)\simeq \nu_4(n!)$

Tags: number-theory, factorial, valuation-theory

$\nu_3(n!)$ and $\nu_4(n!)$ ($\nu$ being the valuation function) seems to have the same value most of the time (on "small numbers").
Here is a table with a few values:

$\begin{array}
\textbf{n} &1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&100&1000&10000&....     \\
\hline
\nu_3(n!) &0&0&1&1&1&2&2&2&4&4&48&498&4996&... \\
\nu_4(n!) &0&0&0&1&1&2&2&3&3&4&48&497&4997&... \\
\end{array}$

> Is it still the case when $n \rightarrow \infty $ ? Is there a bound on the difference ? How often are they equal ?

From a density perspective, they seem to have almost the same coverage:

$\nu_3(n!)=\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{3^k} \rfloor$

$\nu_4(n!)=\lfloor \frac{n+2}{8} \rfloor+\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{4^k} \rfloor$

$\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{3^k}=\frac{1}{2}$

$\frac{1}{8}+\sum\limits_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{4^k}=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{11}{24}\simeq\frac{1}{2}$

It feels like I am missing an obvious link, but the more I dig the less find it obvious...

EDIT: bounds added (Thx Trebor)

$\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n}\leq \frac{\nu_3(n!)}{n}\leq \frac{1}{3-1}$

$\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{3}{4n}\leq \frac{\nu_4(n!)}{n}\leq \frac{1}{4-1}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4n}$

and for $n \rightarrow \infty $

$.333...\leq \frac{\nu_3(n!)}{n}\leq .5$

$.375\leq \frac{\nu_4(n!)}{n}\leq .458333...$

EDIT2: Thanks to the comments

$\nu_4(n!)\simeq\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{2\cdot4^k}+\frac{1}{4} \rfloor+\sum\limits_{k\geq 1} \lfloor \frac{n}{4^k} \rfloor$

So the density is indeed $\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: You can attain a lower bound by assuming each floor function shaves 1 off the total.

Comment: How do you define the valuation function for a composite number like $4$ ?

Comment: @Peter, For this one I just counted the numbers $x\equiv 2 \mod(4)$ which combined in pairs gives an additional factor 4 in the factorial (2, 6, 10, 14, 18, ...).

Comment: Also $8$ and $24$ give an extra $4$ and so on, so the $1/8$ should be multiplied by $4/3$, giving a total of $1/2$, same as $\nu_3$

Comment: @Empy2, Peter,  Thx !!! Missed that one

Comment: So you are just defining $v_4(n!)=\lfloor v_2(n!)/2\rfloor$. You have a formula for $v_2(n!)$

Comment: It should be straightforward to derive a logarithmic bound on the difference. Powers of two and three are kind of the extremal cases. For example, with $n=729$ we get $\nu_3(729!)=364$, $\nu_4(729!)=361$. OTOH $\nu_3(1024!)=508$, $\nu_4(1024!)=511$.
It feels likely that the difference is unbounded, but that is not trivial to prove.

Comment: Since $\nu_3$ jumps by $k$ at $n=3^k$, the difference either before or after the jump must be at least $k/2$, which is unbounded.

Comment: A cool observation, @Empy2. Could be an answer? I was thinking that I need some non-trivial result (from Diophantine approximation) to prove unboundedness (via base 2/3 digit sums). May be I should retire :-)